# is there any API by google to create project for Google assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am creating a UI app, through which i am able to create Voice User interaction through drag and drop feature, Now my entire set of Entities and Intents are created in the form of .json file.

Is there any api by google to create a project in Google actions console, and also create agent in Dialogflow and import my zip into dialogflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are APIs for [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects) project management, but there is no API to create or control projects through the Actions console.